# Edit finger numbers in a Synthesia midi-file

Tags: software, midi, fingering

How can I edit the finger numbers in the midi-files for [Synthesia](https://www.synthesiagame.com/)? Do midi-files support this possibility?

Answer (score 3):

synthesia has a forum which is a much better place to ask questions about synthesia.

but midi files don't have a standard way of storing fingering.  there are a couple unstandard ways to go about it.  but synthesia puts it in a different file ("meta file") altogether.  I think there's a utility in synthesia to copy that info for other people.  but it's not stored in the midi file.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen pointed out, MIDI does not have the facility to cope with fingering information. But it is straightforward to add fingering in Synthesia itself.

From https://www.synthesiagame.com/support/guide/contentCreators

> **Telling Synthesia which parts belong to the left and right hand**
>
> Set both parts using the small 'hand' icon in the advanced view of the song setup screen.
>
> The simple song settings view where a user is able to choose which part they want to play and the mode -- melody, rhythm, or recital -- is a great time-savings and convenience. With the new song progression metric introduced in 0.8.3 that works with the simple view to track how far a user has progressed in a song, there is even more motivation to set your song up to work with the simple view.
>
> If your song only has one or two tracks (along with any amount of percussion), Synthesia should already be able to guess which hand is which. There is no work to do. Your song should appear using the simple view to begin with.
>
> Otherwise, if your song contains a few other background tracks, you'll have to tell Synthesia which one or two are the important ones that the user will be interested in. On the advanced view (which should appear by default if you've got more than two tracks), there is a small hand icon near the instrument name for each track. Click that and assign which hand that part belongs to. Once you've assigned both a "Left Hand" and "Right Hand" (or a single "Both"), the next time you enter that screen it should pop up in the simple view instead. You can test this by tapping escape and selecting your song again.
>
> **Adding finger hints**
>
> Press N to start editing, drag from notes to fingers to add hints.
>
> TIP: Use the 1-5 and 6-0 keys on your keyboard to assign hints to the left or right hand quickly!
> Finger hints are a great way to help beginners learn the correct hand positions and movements required to play a song. You can add finger hints to notes directly during song playback. Just click the finger hint toolbar icon (or press the default keyboard shortcut: N) and you're ready to add them. Place your mouse over a note, then click and drag to one of the fingers that appear near the note. Release over the finger and you're done.
>
> Like finger hints in sheet music, it's best to keep them minimal, only showing when a hand position or finger changes for a particular note. If you're building a lesson for more advanced students you can even leave hints off for common motions or repeated sections where they should already know the fingering.